# Sublime Text: "for loop" text insert?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Let's say I'm writing a JSON object with a lot of properties following this naming convention:

```
ObjectName[x]
```

So it looks like this:

```
ObjectName_A: ...
ObjectName_B: ...
ObjectName_C: ...
...
ObjectName_Z: ...
```

If this were an Excel column, I would have selected two or three names from the name column, clicked on the small black square and pulled down to save myself a lot of typing. Is there a way to do the same thing in Sublime Text?